# In welchem Fall kann »Ring« mit sächlichem Artikel verwendet werden?

Tags: gender

Bei einer Internetrecherche traf ich auf die Wiedergabe von Wagners Opus Magnum als »Das Ring des Niebelungen« (Rechtschreibung unkorrigiert übernommen). Warum heißt es nicht »Der Ring«?

Comment: Ich würde vermuten: Wenn die Rechtschreibung nicht stimmt, ist es mit der Grammatik auch nicht weit her.

Comment: Wo hast du das denn gefunden? Mir ist es nur in englischsprachigen Texten aufgefallen, außerdem gibt es eine Aufnahme, die auf Englisch fälschlicherweise derartig betitelt wird, obwohl das Cover die korrekte Schreibweise zeigt.

Comment: @OrgenGhost Das war tatsächlich eine englische Quelle. Interessant ist z.B., das »[Das Ring des Niebelungen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_Ring_des_Niebelungen)« auf »Der Ring des Nibelungen« weiterleitet, also scheint diese Falschschreibung recht verbreitet zu sein, oder‽

Comment: Eine einzelne Fehlschreibung zu thematisieren - die nachträglich gebrachte Quelle gehört i.d. Frage. - was soll das? Frag denjenigen, der es bei Amazon eingestellt hat. Er wird kaum Deutsch können, und einen Fehler gemacht haben. Off topic, imho. +Close. Könnte gleich aus 4 Gründen geschlossen werden: Too localized, off topic, low quality, not of interest.

Comment: Warum soll die Frage off topic sein? Warum erhält die Frage downvotes? Das ist eine Frage nach der Korrektheit einer Deutschübersetzung. Ist GL&U nicht genau für sowas geschaffen? Warum soll die Frage z. B. schlechter sein als die nach "der Zeh" vs. "die Zehe"?

Comment: Weil jedes Wörterbuch die Frage eindeutig beantwortet, und GL&U kein Wörterbuchersatz sein will - siehe FAQ. Der Zeh/die Zehe ist dagegen beides möglich und wird auch in den Wörterbüchern beides stehen, so dass dieser Sonderfall thematisiert werden kann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natürlich heißt es "**Der** Ring des Nibelungen", wie man auf einer Replik der Partitur unschwer erkennen kann:

[image]

<sup>Quelle: [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:El_anillo_de_los_Nibelungos.jpg) (Public domain)</sup>

Ein [Ring ist maskulin](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ring) und wird auch nicht anderweitig verwendet.

Comment: Ist mir auch klar. Ich frage mich nur, woher diese Falschschreibung stammt.

Comment: Ist mir auch klar, dass Dir das klar ist - ich fand nur das Bild so schön. Woher dieser Fehler kommt, ist mir allerdings auch ein Rätsel.

Comment: Danke für das Bild! Man kann »Das Ring« übrigens auch [kaufen](http://www.amazon.ca/Das-Ring-Niebelungen-Richard-Wagner/dp/tracks/B000000WP5), obwohl das Bild »der« schreibt.

Comment: Das Ring des Weckers hat mich geweckt. Vielleicht hat jmd. ernstlich misverstanden, was mit 'Ring' gemeint ist. Ringelingeling.

Answer (score 4):

Googling for "Das Ring", I get these and similar results:

- Amazon.com: Wagner, R.: Rheingold (Das) (Ring Cycle 1): Roland ...

This means 'Das Rheingold, Ring Cycle 1' - the 'das' belongs to Rheingold.

- Krishna Das - Ring Song/Siya Ram

'Das' seems to be a name here, belonging to 'Krishna', not to 'Ring'.

- Das Ring Festival ist Upon Us | FineArtsLA.com

A classical Deppenleerzeichen. 'Das Ringfestival' is meant.

---

Die meisten Funde passen in diese 3 Kategorien:

1. Fremdsprachige Seiten, die mutmaßlich von nicht so gut Deutsch sprechenden Personen bestückt wurden, die im Irrtum über das richtige Geschlecht 'das' schrieben.
2. Deppenleerzeichen, bei denen sich das 'das' auf ein Wort bezieht, das dem 'Ring' erst folgt.
3. Interferenzen, bei denen das 'das' sich nur scheinbar auf den Ring bezieht. Es steht vor 'Ring', aber nicht als sein bestimmter Artikel.

Keineswegs gibt es ein alternatives Geschlecht für Ring, ist es eine altdeutsche oder regionale Schreibweise. Es ist einfach falsch, und kann in jedem Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen werden.

Für "Die Ring des Nibelungen" findet Google übrigens auch allerhand. Vielleicht eine hübsche Folgefrage.